# Year changing from negative -509 to a positive 510 in JDBC with H2 Database

Tags: java, jdbc, java-8, h2, localdate

## `-509` vs `510`

I am seeing some kind of altered or erroneous data, with the use of JDBC. So I observe using [H2 Database](http://h2database.com/) version 1.4.196 on Java 8 Update 151.

Here is a complete example.

Note how we retrieve the date value three times, first as a `LocalDate` object, secondly as text, and thirdly as an `int` year number extracted from a cast `LocalDate` object. In the text version we can see that the year is indeed negative. Mysteriously the `LocalDate` has a different year number and it is positive rather than negative. Seems like a bug.

```
private void doIt ( )
{
    System.out.println( "BASIL - Running doIt." );
    try
    {
        Class.forName( "org.h2.Driver" );
    } catch ( ClassNotFoundException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace( );
    }

    try (
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:h2:mem:" ) ;  // Unnamed throw-away in-memory database.
    )
    {
        conn.setAutoCommit( true );
        String sqlCreate = "CREATE TABLE history  ( id IDENTITY , when  DATE ); ";
        String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO history ( when ) VALUES ( ? ) ; ";
        String sqlQueryAll = "SELECT * FROM history  ; ";

        PreparedStatement psCreate = conn.prepareStatement( sqlCreate );

        psCreate.executeUpdate( );

        PreparedStatement psInsert = conn.prepareStatement( sqlInsert );

        psInsert.setObject( 1 , LocalDate.of( 2017 , 1 , 23 ) );
        psInsert.executeUpdate( );

        psInsert.setObject( 1 , LocalDate.of( -509 , 1 , 1 ) );
        psInsert.executeUpdate( );

        PreparedStatement psQueryAll = conn.prepareStatement( sqlQueryAll );
        ResultSet rs = psQueryAll.executeQuery( );
        while ( rs.next( ) )
        {
            long l = rs.getLong( 1 );  // Identity column.
            // Retrieve the same date value in three different ways.
            LocalDate ld = rs.getObject( 2 , LocalDate.class );  // Extract a `LocalDate`, and implicitly call its `toString` method that uses standard ISO 8601 formatting.
            String s = rs.getString( 2 );  // Extract the date value as text from the database using the database-engine’s own formatting.
            int y = ( ( LocalDate ) rs.getObject( 2 , LocalDate.class ) ).getYear( );  // Extract the year number as an integer from a `LocalDate` object.
            String output = "ROW: " + l+ " | " + ld + " | when as String: " + s+ " | year: " + y ;
            System.out.println( output );
        }

        conn.close( );
    } catch ( SQLException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace( );
    }
}
```

When run.

> ROW: 1 | 2017-01-23 | when as String: 2017-01-23 | year: 2017
>
> ROW: 2 | 0510-01-01 | when as String: -509-01-01 | year: 510

So there seems to be something going on with JDBC being involved. Note how the year is presented as a positive 510 rather than a negative 509. I do not understand this behavior.

I can deduce that it is an issue within [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) rather than within [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). See this [example code run live in IdeOne.com](https://www.ideone.com/iVb7PW) showing that a `LocalDate` object does indeed carry and report a negative year.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( -509 , 1 , 1 ) ;
System.out.println( "ld.toString(): " + ld ) ;
System.out.println( "ld.getYear(): " + ld.getYear() ) ;
```

Notice how we do *not* get converted from -509 to 510 when dealing with a `LocalDate` only, with no JDBC.

> ld: -0509-01-01
>
> ld.getYear(): -509

I opened a [Issue ticket](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/644) on the H2 project.

Comment: Interesting issue.  I know next to nothing about JDBC, but a hunch would be that some form of underflow is occurring.

Comment: Inspired by [Why quering a date BC is changed to AD in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46835047/why-quering-a-date-bc-is-changed-to-ad-in-java)? Not that the connection is important to the question.

Comment: Sounds more to me like a bug where someone forgot to pass the era along. But this is guesswork.

Comment: See also the [related issue on GitHub](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/644).

Comment: This issue [has been fixed in the H2 source](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/pull/708) and should be included in releases after 1.4.196.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Bug, fixed

This problem was due to a [bug in H2](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/pull/708).

Now fixed, as of 2018-01.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is caused by the conversion from `java.sql.Date` to `LocalDate`
.
Because it's a negative year, the `Calendar` instance holding the fetched result will transform the **year** to **1 - year** but when converting to `LocalDate` java is not considering the additional information **(era==BC)** that indicates that the `year < 0` The following is the final method executed before returning the result. 
[image]

try this one :

```
public class Test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

            Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
            instance.set(-509,1,1);

            java.sql.Date d = new Date(instance.getTime().getTime());

            System.out.println(d.toLocalDate().getYear());// 510


        }
}
```

Thanks  Ole V.V. for your comment!!!

Comment: Yeah, but in that case it also sets era to BC, so all the information should still be in there for producing the correct `LocalDate`. There must be something more going on, mustn’t there? Thank you for a partial explanation though.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**: If the JDBC driver internally uses a `java.sql.Date` and converts it using `java.sql.Date.toLocalDate()`, a suspected bug in the deprecated `Date.getYear()` will (at least sometimes) cause the behaviour you observed.

This is guesswork, but I found it interesting enough to share.

I gather from [SEY_91’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46847155/5772882) that the driver does use one or more of the legacy date and time classes, at least `Calendar` and `GregorianCalendar`. There are more conversion paths from `Calendar` to `LocalDate`, so the one via `java.sql.Date` is just one of them. Other conversion paths may hit the same bug, though.

Fact: The `toLocalDate` method relies on the deprecated `getYear` method. Source:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public LocalDate toLocalDate() {
    return LocalDate.of(getYear() + 1900, getMonth() + 1, getDate());
}
```

To see how `getYear` behaves with a year before the common era, I tried:

```
    OffsetDateTime dateTimeBce 
            = OffsetDateTime.of(-509, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneOffset.ofHours(1));
    Date d = Date.from(dateTimeBce.toInstant());
    System.out.println("d.toInstant() " + d.toInstant());
    System.out.println("d.getYear() (deprecated): " + d.getYear() 
                        + ", means " + (d.getYear() + 1900));
```

Since the year from `getYear` is “1900-based”, the expected year would be -2409. If we added 1900 to this, we would get -509, the year we started out from. However, the snippet prints:

```
d.toInstant() -0510-12-31T23:00:00Z
d.getYear() (deprecated): -1390, means 510
```

The first line shows that the `Date` does contain a negative year as it should (the offset conversion to UTC changes the year from -509 to -510; I chose the standard time offset of my computer’s time zone setting). The snippet uses `java.util.Date`, but `java.sql.Date` inherits the `getYear` method, and I have reproduced similar behaviour with `java.sql.Date` too.

I made a brief Internet search for any mention of the suspected bug without finding anything. We may want to try harder.

Comment: But why is the string value (`rs.getString( 2 )`) showing the correct negative year?

Comment: Interesting question, @MickMnemonic. The easy answer is that it is not going through the same (buggy) conversion. My guess is the string is generated on the database side and passed as string from there, but I don’t know, of course.